# How do I setState in my react-leaflet component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-leaflet

I cannot update state in my `componentDidMount` using `setState`. I have an axios call that handles the asynchronous call to my api and loads an anonymous function which should update state when the user clicks on the `geoJSON` layer. For some reason the redux store is not being updated on click and remains the initial state of an empty string. My code is below

```
import React from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';
import {apiKey} from './apiKey';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';
import {districtStyle, districtHighlightStyle, mapStyle} from './styles';

class Map extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {

    let districtsJSON = null;

    this.map = L.map('map').setView([31.15, -99.90], 6);

    L.tileLayer(`https://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/pioneer/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=${apiKey}`, {
      attribution: 'Pioneer Basemap by Thunderforest, a project by Gravitystorm Limited.'
    }).addTo(this.map);


    const districtsUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/gerrymander/api/districts/';
    axios.get(districtsUrl).then(
      response => {
        districtsJSON = response.data;

        const txDistricts = L.geoJson(districtsJSON, {
          style: districtStyle,
          onEachFeature: (feature, layer) => {
            layer.on({
              click: (e) => {
                if (lastClickedLayer !== e.target) {
                  txDistricts.setStyle(districtStyle);
                }
                e.target.setStyle(districtHighlightStyle);
                let lastClickedLayer = e.target;
                // Set state to the target layer's clicked district
                this.setState({ district: e.target.feature.properties.namelsad })
              }
            });
          }
        }).addTo(this.map);
      }
    )
    console.log(this.props.district);
  }

  render() {
    return <div id="map" style={mapStyle}></div>
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    district: state.district,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Map);
```

Comment: Just wondering whether a `setState` would work without initializing a state

Comment: I initialize state in my redux store.

Comment: Ok. My guess is that your `componentDidMount` is called once when the page renders so when you click it is not re-rendering the page. Thats why there is an empty string.

Comment: Can you create a demo to reproduce the issue?